# Multiple select drop down user control or field control

Tags: sharepoint, layout

I want to use multiple select drop down user control or field control on my page layout and I want to pull list items from list and show it on page layout in Sharepoint.Does anyone is having idea how to achieve this.

Thanks,
PS

Comment: It can be like list box control.But I am not able to add list box control into page layout.

Comment: Could you add some context to what more generally you are trying to do please and I might be able to give you an answer

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint Designer, go to:

- Insert, SharePoint Controls, DataView
- on the DataSource Library panel, choose a list and click "Show Data"
- Drag and Drop a few fields from the Data Source Details
- go to the Toolbox Tab in the same panel as Data Source Details and choose: "Data View Checkbox List"
- Configure as you like

**Edit based on your reply**

If I understand your reply right, how about you have a Yes/No column(field) in your list named "IsVisible" with a Custom View where only items *WHERE IsVisible Equals Yes* on the web part and the Administrator will just edit the list and change the value for the Visible field.